# AngularJS $scope.form.$submitted shows true

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

I have a multi-step form and I want to control the user if he submitted a valid information in each step. I am checking for validation, and if true, i move to next step, but the $scope.form.$submitted shows True and the ng-message pops up.

```
function stepForward(step){
            console.log($scope.AdvertiserRegistration.$valid);
            if($scope.AdvertiserRegistration.$valid){
                var t = setTimeout(function(){
                    $scope.AdvertiserRegistration.$submitted = false;
                },3000);
                window.location = '#/advertiser/register/step'+step;
            }

        }
```

So this is my function and it's not working:

`console.log($scope.AdvertiserRegistration.$valid)` returns True.

Any solution?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this $scope.AdvertiserRegistration.$submitted = false?

Comment: You do realize that your window.location will happen instantaneous and yet $submitted is only going to be updated 3 seconds later (I'm assuming you are simulating a server postback of 3 secs?).

Comment: so @wdanda what do you suggest in this case ?

Comment: depends on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to validate in the server side for each step to see if the user has entered valid data? If thats the case I wouldn't send the user immediately to the next step, I'd call the server (and show a "please wait" message), and once the call is resolved you can the either show an error message or if succeeded (i.e. user data is valid) then and only then do the redirect to the next step.

Comment: @wdanda no i am not validating this server side. All I want is a much simpler solution without the:

var t = setTimeout(function(){
                    $scope.AdvertiserRegistration.$submitted = false;
                },3000);

only with : $scope.AdvertiserRegistration.$submitted = false;

because you said that 

window.location = '#/advertiser/register/step'+step; does the trouble here.

so how can i replace the 

window.location = '#/advertiser/register/step'+step; in this case to work with the ui-router ?

Comment: well I still don't get what ur trying to do lol. But all good, you have marked an answer as solution, so assuming this is okay now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using angular any async operation takes you out of the angular digest cycle, so the angular team provides services for these operations, one of them is `$timeout`, change your code to this:

```
function stepForward(step){
            console.log($scope.AdvertiserRegistration.$valid);
            if($scope.AdvertiserRegistration.$valid){
                //YOU NEED TO INJECT $timeout
                var t = $timeout(function(){
                    $scope.AdvertiserRegistration.$submitted = false;
                },3000);
                window.location = '#/advertiser/register/step'+step;
            }

        }
```